# include variable with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I´ve just started to learn JavaScript and made a click function to change value of `i` depending on which `li` element is being clicked. Instead of having 3x of basically same function is it possible to send variable with `addEventLisener` to check with a `if statement`. Because if I add 1 or 2 more `li` it would add a lot of unnecessary code.

HTML:

```
<div><img src="image1" />
<ul>
<li id="list1">1</li>
<li id="list2">2</li>
<li id="list3">3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var list1 = getElementById('list1');
var list2 = getElementById('list2');
var list3 = getElementById('list3');

list1.addEventListener("click", clicked1);
list2.addEventListener("click", clicked2);
list3.addEventListener("click", clicked3);
var i = 0;

function clicked1(){
    i= 0;
    loop();
}
function clicked2(){
    i = 1;
    loop();
}
function clicked3(){
    i = 2;
    loop();
}
function loop(){
    if (i > 2){
        i=0;
    }
    var imageloop = getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img');
    imageloop[0].src = 'image' +  i;
    i++
    setTimeout(loop,3000);

}
```

So when one of the `li` element is being clicked it will change the img currently displaying.

Comment: Listen clicks on `ul`, in the handler function extract the number from the `id` of the [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and use that instead of `i`. Short and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Separate code for each `<li>`,

Here is How to do it in single function:

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul id="All_List">
<li id="list1">1</li>
<li id="list2">2</li>
<li id="list3">3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var clicked_li=0; /* It'll store the number of <li> being clicked */
var ul=document.getElementById("All_List"); /* <ul> Element with all <li> */
window.onload=function(){
var lis=ul.getElementsByTagName("li"); /* All <li>'s from <ul> */
for(var i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
var li=lis[i]; /* Specific <li> from <ul> ie, lis[0] means first <li> of <ul> */
    li.addEventListener("click", function(){  /* Listen and bind click event to that <li> */
    clicked_li=getIndex(this);  /* Store Which <li> Was clicked in clicked_li */
    alert("'list"+clicked_li+"' was clicked!");  
     /* if you just want to get the id you can use event.target.id; instead of getIndex(); */
    }, false);
}
};

function getIndex(node) {
var childs = node.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("li"); /* Get parent <ul> and all child <li> of that parent */
for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
 if (node == childs[i]) break; /* Find which <li> from current <ul> was clicked */
 }
return (i+1); /* Return No.(index) of that <li> starting with 1 */
}
```

and here is the:


## **`fiddle`**

 for the same.

Hope it'll help you. Cheers!

Comment: i just don't know what people think when they downvote, it's none of their concern but still they do. this is really bad of SO. they must compulsory the comment with downvote otherwise it is of no use.

Comment: personally i think this a quite good answer, Since the group of li elemets function clicked represents Nodelist which starts from 0 rather than 1. instead of going after id which in first case i wanted to remove for a more dynamic approth, +1

Comment: I didn't down-vote but your code promotes anti-patterns, non-scalability, duplicate, redundant, and implicit variable declaration, and chaotic syntax formatting - all in the same answer. How this answer got any up-votes at all is a mystery, let alone was the accepted answer is what's "really bad of SO", because now future people who have event delegation questions will come here and see your terrible suggestions and think that's what they should be doing. If this is your best answer, great, thanks for the effort - complaining when you get called out, grow up.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Thanks for explaining what was wrong with that code, I've edited it, Hope its nice now. Well and for the second part I'm here to help peoples, which  i like most, So when some one criticizes(downvote) I believe (s)he should at least tell what is wrong? and yeah I'm not here to give my best, but just to help peoples to get there code work. Also I'm not complaining. Yeah every one has right to express their view. I was trying to give suggestion to SO team that they can improve the enthusiasm of users using simple techniques. +1 for explaining.

Comment: @Nicco, I'm glad that i could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the list, not the list item - `<ul id="ul1">...` :

```
document.getElementById('ul1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var li = e.target;
    alert(li.id); // list1, list2, respectively, etc.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/D6HX4/

Comment: This is a good start, adding just a bit of code and this works like a charm. To what i need to use it for.

Answer (score 2):

As Teemu said, bind to the list and use `e.target`. Then, change `i` according to `e.target.innerHTML` (because for your purposes, that's easier since the `innerHTML` is similar to the `id`, but simpler).

Assuming the `<ul>` element now has an `id` of `"list"`:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var i = null;
list.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    window.i = parseInt(e.target.innerHTML, 10);
    console.log(window.i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an "improve/clearer" of Vedant Terkar answer. Which may give a more clear aspect on 
the answer he gave.

if we give `ul` id group. We dont need id for each of the list-item inside the `ul`.

```
<ul id="group">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var i=0;
```

we set `i` to be a global variable and equal to 0 assuming it will display image(0) if nothing else is called.

```
window.onload=function(){
  var lis=document.getElementById("group").getElementsByTagName('li');
```

We are now creating a `Nodelist` which is called `lis`. Then we loop through the `NodeList` to se which list-element is being clicked at.

```
  for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
    var li=lis[i];
    li.addEventListener("click",index, false);
  }
}

function index(){ 
  var lis = document.getElementById("group").getElementsByTagName('li');
  i = getIndex(this);
  for(var a=0; a < lis.length; a++){
    if(a ==i){
      lis[i].innerHTML = 'Choosen';     
    }else{
      lis[a].innerHTML = 'list'+a;  
    }

  }
}

function getIndex(node) {
  var childs = node.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if (node == childs[i]) break;
  }
  return (i);
}
```